# AngularJS: function always evaluates to false because of Async nature of service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

My Template looks like

```
<div data-ng-if="budgetSummaryExists()">
        <span>You have not budget</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                data-ng-click="setRoute('budgets')">Create
            Budget
        </button>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-if="$scope.budgetSummaryExists">
        <span>your budget summary exists</span>
    </div>
```

My Controller looks like

```
function BudgetSummaryController($scope, $location, BudgetSummary) {
    /* For default view when budgets is clicked */
    $scope.thisMonthBudgetSummary = function () {
        console.log('retrieving budget summary');

        var date = new Date();
        BudgetSummary.get({'month': date.getMonth() + 1, 'year': date.getFullYear()},
            function (data) {
                $scope.budgetSummary = data;

                // success
                console.log('budgetSummary:', data);
            },
            function (error) {
                //error
                console.log('error:', error.status);
            })

        ;
    };

    $scope.budgetSummaryExists = function () {
        return $scope.budgetSummary !== undefined;
    }
```

**Problem**
- Even before the service returns the data `budgetSummaryExists()` evaluates to false and I do not see other part of DOM

**Question**

How can I make sure that function `budgetSummaryExists()` only evaluates when service is done getting the data from server?

Answer (score 0):

My Template was wrong, this fixed it

```
    <div data-ng-if="! budgetSummaryExists()">
        <span>You have not budget</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                data-ng-click="setRoute('budgets')">Create
            Budget
        </button>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-if="budgetSummaryExists()">
        <span>your budget summary exists</span>
    </div>
```